# How to create version API in CI

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to create `API` for my android application Like :
For version 1 `api URL` will be

```
www.example.com/api/v1/list
```

And for `Version 1.1` api url will be

```
www.example.com/api/v1_1/list
```

Comment: sounds like fun - if you run into problems be sure to come back and ask

Answer (score 0):

**You can follow below steps for APIs version controlling :**

1) define route name with folder wise

```
$route['api/v1/common/servicelist'] = 'version_1.0/CommonController/servicelist';
$route['api/v1/common/itemlist'] = 'version_1.0/CommonController/itemlist';
$route['api/v1_1/common/servicelist'] = 'version_1.1/CommonController/servicelist';
$route['api/v1_1/common/itemlist'] = 'version_1.1/CommonController/itemlist';
```

2) Make individual folder for controllers files

```
application/controllers/version_1.0/CommonController.php
application/controllers/version_1.1/CommonController.php
```

3) You can manage different version APIs by single models file

Hope this helps you.